# Preseeding in Ubuntu installer

Tags: iso, preseed

I want to run a few commands immediately after installation of Ubuntu.Therefore I thought of using preseeding concept.I extracted my iso and in the preseed folder appended the following line to custom.seed file

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target mkdir /home/abc
```

Now I repacked the iso and installed ubuntu using it..But no change happened..What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, this question is a bit thin on the facts, but my guess would be that `mkdir` isn't being found or some such. If I were you I'd use a shell script with a proper hashbang that refers to a shell you _know_ to be present when the `late_command` gets to run. There can anyway only be a single `late_command` ...

Comment: Also, are you certain that `in-target` will be found? I'd probably also try to make sure to use the full path or something akin to `chroot /target <yourcommand>` ...

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a lot of frustration preseeding `xubuntu 20.04 desktop`.  Ultimately this is what worked for me:

From "using preseed files" in [UbiquityAutomation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation).

Specifying a preseed file is not enough, the boot code `'automatic-ubiquity'` or the ubiquity command with the `--automatic` argument is also necessary.

The iso `txt.cfg/grub.cfg` starts up with `only-ubiquity`. So, if you did not modify those files and just added the preseed file and then repacked, it will not work.